# show a popup link after video play

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I am working on this **[site](http://www.stanshyshkin.com/king/)** the home page slider has an option with label Watch the video I have added the below codes to my templates for the video to work.

```
<script>
function videoshow()
 {
 document.getElementById("sliders-container").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("show-video").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("show-video").innerHTML="<span id='close-button' onclick='closevideo()'>close</span><video id='example_video_1' class='video-js vjs-default-skin' controls   width='100%' data-setup='{}' autoplay><source src='http://constantin-entertainment.info/king/wp-content/themes/Avada/video/sample11.mp4' type='video/mp4' /><source src='http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm' type='video/webm' /><source src='http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv' type='video/ogg' /><track kind='captions' src='demo.captions.vtt' srclang='en' label='English'></track><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 --><track kind='subtitles' src='demo.captions.vtt' srclang='en' label='English'></track><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 --><p class='vjs-no-js'>To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href='http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/' target='_blank'>supports HTML5 video</a></p> </video>";
 }

function closevideo()
{

   document.getElementById("show-video").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("show-video").innerHTML="";
     document.getElementById("sliders-container").style.display="block";

} 

</script>
```

and the below div for the video to show

```
<div id="show-video">

</div>
```

and called the below files also

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/video.js"></script>
```

the videos are playing firn in all browsers.Now  I would like a box to hover out like "**Contact Me**" with a link to my contact form.so I searched over net and applied the following code

```
<script>
var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

video.onended = function(e) {
  <a href="#contact">Conatct Me</a>
};
</script>
```

but didnt help. Not sure where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i think your are writing wrong syntax.

code should be like that

```
<script>
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    video.onended = function () {

        $('<a href="#contact">Conatct Me</a>').appendTo('#example_video_1');

    };  
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would user JQuery for that, just download the js files and then include them in ur file with:

```
<script src="[path]"></script>
```

now you can do this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
   var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
   video.onended = function(e) {
      $('#contact').html('<a href="#contact">Conatct Me</a>');
   }
}

</script>
```

if this dont works pleas write the JS error as comment.

**EDIT:**

Totaly forgot about that you can also change the text in the DIV without any JQuery:

```
<script> 
    document.getElementById('contact').innerHTML = '<a href="#contact">Conatct Me</a>'; 
</script>
```

Comment: not it shows Revolution Slider Error: You have some jquery.js library include that comes after the revolution files js include.
This includes make eliminates the revolution slider libraries, and make it not work.

To fix it you can:
    1. In the Slider Settings -> Troubleshooting set option: Put JS Includes To Body option to true.
    2. Find the double jquery.js include and remove it.

Comment: do it without the JQuery, look at the edit and add the line at the line where u want to set the link appearing, that should be in the 'video.onended' function.